# Font didn't Work - Vim Statusline

Tags: linux, macos, vim, vim-plugin

I've installed and tested some statuslines (VIM Airline - VIM Lightline, etc) with some plugins (VIM Fugitive, VIM NERDtree, etc...), everythings works... except for the fonts.

I work from my Mac OSX to a Linux server where i connect via `ssh`.

I have not yet understood:

1. Where do I install the fonts? On my Mac or on my Linux Server? I have already installed the font on my Mac and i have already set "guifont" in my vimrc file on my Linux server with no success.
2. How to install a patched font? The guides that I've found online do not resolve this issue.

I just want to see the special characters while working with Vim on my Linux server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect via SSH from Mac OS to Linux, Vim runs on the Linux system, but you're interacting with it through the *terminal emulator* program on Mac OS. The SSH protocol (as the older *telnet*) is based on just exchanging pressed keys and printed output (which includes special control sequences to reposition the cursor, change colors and text attributes, but **not** font changes - there's only a single default font involved).

As you're running terminal Vim, not the graphical GVIM, the `'guifont'` option doesn't apply here. Instead, you need to configure the font in the Mac OS *terminal emulator* program (and that will then apply not only to Vim, but to any SSH connection to any remote computer).

#### Alternative

Linux systems use the *X protocol* for graphical programs. As this program is *remotable*, you can forward the user interface to another system, e.g. with `ssh -X <hostname>`. This requires a running X environment on your (Mac OS) client. As the X protocol exchanges keypresses, mouse events, and graphical updates (like the Remote Desktop for Windows), here, the font settings are entirely determined by the Linux system, and `'guifont'` applies.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, i have to install the font on my Mac (already done), and then? I'm trying to put the 'guifont' option in my .vimrc on Linux and didn't work. So? I have to set the 'guifont' option also in my .vimrc on my Mac or i have to configure my terminal simulator (in this case iTerm2).

Thank you!

Comment: You need to configure your custom font in iTerm2, right. Vim over SSH will then use that.

Comment: I resolved! I'd to patch my font with this guide (https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/tree/develop/fontpatcher) and then i select the font from my terminal simulator (iTerm).